# containerized reverse proxy showing default site

Tags: docker, nginx

No matter what I do, I keep running into the problem where my website publishes the default nginx website. I'm trying to dockerize my webserver such that it can point to home assistant running in another container. I've been able to get it to work when both were hosted on the same raspi, not running in containers, but not when both are running in containers.

I've attached my nginx.conf, Dockerfile and default.conf that I was using to start the environment up. I've spent the last 2 days looking for someone who was trying to do something similar, but I assume I'm making such a stupid mistake that most have been able to figure it out on their own..

nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

default.conf (/etc/nginx/conf.d/hass.conf)

```
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    # Update this line to be your domain
    server_name nekohouse.ca;

    # These shouldn't need to be changed
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=off;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    # Update this line to be your domain
    server_name nekohouse.ca;

    # Ensure these lines point to your SSL certificate and key
    ssl_certificate fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key privkey.pem;
    # Use these lines instead if you created a self-signed certificate
    # ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
    # ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem;

    # Ensure this line points to your dhparams file
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;


    # These shouldn't need to be changed
    listen [::]:443 default_server ipv6only=off; # if your nginx version is >= 1.9.5 you can also add the "http2" flag here
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";
    ssl on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    proxy_buffering off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8123;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect http:// https://;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

default.conf (/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf)

```
server {
    listen       8100;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of this line

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8123;
```

When running in containers, you should understand that `localhost` refers to the `nginx` container and not the docker host.

So, you should either change `localhost` to the hostname of your docker host or use `docker-compose` so that you can change it to the name of the container defined.

If you are just running the containers separately, you could also just use the container IP for now but note that it will change everytime the container is restarted.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I thought this might be the problem, so I built a docker-compose.yml file. Shortened version:

`version: '3'

services:
    homeassistant:
      networks:
        - hass
    nginx:
      networks:
        - hass
networks:
    hass:`

I also changed that `localhost` line to:

`http://<stackname>_homeassistant:8123;`

It runs.. but it's still not forwarding to my other container...